# Are there sampling profilers for stripped binaries?

Tags: dynamic-analysis

I have a stripped binary in which I need to find the code for a particular function. I can run the binary on input which will make it spend a significant percentage of CPU time in that function. Maybe 5%-10% and the app is multi threaded.

So I can probably just run it under GDB (it's on Linux), break it a few times with `C-c` and have a good chance of hitting the function.

This approach is a bit like a sampling profiler, just done manually. Which brings me to the question: is there a tool which I could use to do this automatically?